# Graph walking: smallest set of "blocking" nodes

Tags: graph-theory

I'm not sure I've got the terminology right in my question, but here's conceptually what I'm looking for.

In a directed acyclic graph with a single root node and multiple end nodes, how can I can determine the smallest set of nodes such as when I remove these nodes (and associated edges) from the graph none of the end nodes are reachable from the root node?

To put my needs in a bit more context, I'm working with a Rete network as obtained by a production rules engine and I'm trying to figure out what is the smallest conditions that would prevent any rule from firing.

Comment: If you wanted the smallest set of *edges* whose removal disconnects the root from the ends, you be talking about a "minimal cut" in a network, and there's a standard algorithm for doing that (maybe you already know that algorithm). So perhaps you could form a dual graph, where the nodes of your graph are the edges of the dual, and then solve the problem on the dual, and interpret the solution in the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r$ be the root node, and $N$ the set of end nodes. I'll assume: (1) removing the root node and any end nodes are not allowed; and (2) that there is no arc from a root node to an end node (otherwise, by assumption (1), there is no solution). Perhaps you do want to allow the removal of end nodes, but I think what I write below is easily modified in this case.

First, add to $G$ a single vertex $s$, and, for every end node $n\in N$, add an arc $(n,s)$ to $G$. Call this new graph $G=(V,A)$ as well.

Note that any directed path from $r$ to an end node $n$ can be uniquely extended to a directed path from $r$ to $s$, and conversely any directed path from $r$ to $s$ can be shortened to a directed path from $r$ to some end node.

Call those vertices in $V\setminus (\{r\}\cup N)$ *deletable.* We want to find a minimum sized set of deletable vertices whose deletion leaves no directed paths from $r$ to $s$. I'll follow you by calling this a "blocking set". By assumption (2), a blocking set at least exists (namely, take $C$ to be all deletable vertices), so we need to find one of minimum size.

For the following, I will have to assume you know a little about the [max-flow min-cut theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem). In particular, I will use notation from that wikipedia article, although it is pretty much the standard notation found in most textbooks. The basic algorithm one can use to find a maximum flow is the [Ford-Fulkerson Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm), which is fast.

Anyway, we're going to apply max-flow min-cut to a new graph $G^\prime=(V^\prime,A^\prime)$ (with edge capacities) obtained from $G$ as follows.

The vertices of $G^\prime$ consist of $r,s,N$, and, for each deletable vertex $v$, two vertices $\{v_1,v_2\}$. For each deletable vertex $v$ in $G$, put into $A^\prime$: the arc $(v_1,v_2)$ (call these, and only these,"unit arcs"); for each arc $(w,v)\in A$, the arc $(w,v_1)$; and for each arc $(v,w)\in A$, the arc $(v_2,w)$. Finally, if $(x,y)$ is an arc in $A$ where neither $x$ or $y$ is deletable, put $(x,y)$ into $A^\prime$.

Finally, give all unit arcs a capacity of $1$, and give all other arcs infinite capacity.

Note that any directed path from $r$ to $s$ in $G$ naturally corresponds to a directed path from $r$ to $s$ in $G^\prime$ and conversely. Moreover, by our starting assumptions, any directed path from $r$ to $s$ in $G$ uses a deletable vertex, and hence the corresponding path in $G^\prime$ uses a unit arc. From this, we may observe that a blocking set $C$ in $G$ corresponds to an $(r,s)$-cut in $G^\prime$ with corresponding cut-set $\{(v_1,v_2) \mid v\in C\}$, where $(v_1,v_2)$ is the unit arc corresponding to $v$. Conversely, any $(r,s)$-cut in $G^\prime$ with finite capacity $c$ corresponds to a blocking set of size $c$ in $G$ (the finite-capacity implies that the cut-set consists only of unit arcs).

The previous paragraph implies that the minimum size of a blocking set equals the minimum capacity of a cut-set in $G^\prime$. Now apply the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm to $G^\prime$ using source $r$ and sink $s$ to get a maximum $(r,s)$-flow. The arcs that are filled to capacity (which are necessarily unit arcs) then correspond to the minimum (capacity) cut-set in $G^\prime$ and hence a minimum blocking set in $G$. The previous sentence is a consequence of the max-flow min-cut theorem.